# How to move comments from EasyBlog to Joomla articles?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I've copied all my Easyblog posts into com_content.

Now, I must add each comment (previously posted on EasyBlog posts) on the right article in Joomla (I am using Komento as comment component).

The ID of the EasyBlog posts must be changed to the new articles ID created in com_content (column cid of the table).

What is the best and simplest way to do this?

Comment: Wouldn't the comments also be located in the database? I'm pretty certain you could move the comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

I would export to CVS and make necessary edits using a text editor then import the newly edited CVS into the SQL database though, there is other ways of accomplishing this using SQL queries.  Make sure you backup your tables first.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by editing database tables.  Download the easyblog (jos_easyblog_articles) table and joomla article (jos_articles) tables. Insert the data from the easyblog tables into your joomla articles table then import the new joomla articles table into your database.

Comment: thanks for answering but i want to add all the **comments ** which are associated with the EasyBlog